# Table subheadings in R

Tags: r

In R I'm trying to output a dataframe with subheadings based on one of the variables. What is needed is csv text with subheads like this (using iris data):

```
# setosa
5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2
4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2
...
# versicolor
7.0, 3.2, 4.7, 1.4
6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5
...
# virginica
6.3, 3.3, 6.0, 2.5
5.8, 2.7, 5.1, 1.9
...
```

What are some of the native commands for handling such a task?  Are there packages which include this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at dplyr, specifically the `filter` function

Comment: Try `split`, e.g. `split(iris[1:4],iris[5])` or `lapply(split(iris[1:4],iris[5]), head, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `cat` and `write.table` with `append = TRUE` to create the output. Note that we will set `append = FALSE` at the beginning.

```
mylist = split(iris, iris$Species)
lapply(1:length(mylist), function(i){
    if (i == 1){
        append = FALSE
    }else{
        append = TRUE
    }
    #Write the name of the Species
    cat(paste0("#",names(mylist)[i],"\n"), file = "~/test.csv", append = append)
    #Write the data corresponding to the above Species
    write.table(mylist[[i]], file = "~/test.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Thanks @d.b this is helpful.